# Origin of the word "sport"

Tags: etymology

I wonder what is the etymology of the word *sport*.

Vasmer says that it is from *disport* "amusement", a contraction from Middle English *disporten* from Old French *desporter* "to take away", "to distract from the work".

But Starostin's Starling site gives another etymology:

Eng. *sport* < Old Eng. *spyrd*, Goth. *spɔrd-s* "racing" < Proto-Germ. **spurd* < PIE **sperdh-* "run competition"

It gives as cognates Hittite *ispart-*, Avest. *sparǝr-* Old Indic *-spūrdhán*, *spárdhate* "competition"

So who is correct?

Note also that Vasmer connects Russian *spor* "dispute" to Avest *pǝrǝt-* and Old Indic *pŕ̥tanā* "struggle" so that the s- in PIE **sperdh-* could be s-mobile.

Also take into account the root **per-* meaning "first", "in front", "against" and Proto-Slavic *perdъ* "before, in front of" < PIE **per-dʰ-o*.

Comment: Does the Starling site give any explanation for the change of "d" to "t"? That seems unexpected to me

Comment: How about ‘spar’ as a possible origin of ‘sport’? Spar meaning to fight or box, but also referring to a ‘spar’ or long stick. Might the origins of sport come from military practice of some kind? I was reading anout the ‘Spartans’ and their hellishly hard regime where slaves relieved men from the need to work, so that men could focus on being an army. And boys were inducted into a harsh military regime at age 7. https://www.livescience.com/32035-sparta.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of OE **spyrd** Bowsorth-Toller says,

> The word glosses ***stadium*** (1) with the meaning ***a course*** :-- Ða ðe in spyrde iornaþ ***qui in stadio currunt***, Rtl. 5, 33. (2) with the meaning ***a measure of distance*** :-- Swelce spyrdas fífténe (spyrdum fífténum, Lind.) ***quasi stadiis quindecim***, Jn. Skt. Rush. 11, 18. Swelce spyrdo fífe and twoegentig ***quasi stadia .xxv.***, 6, 19. Ðara spyrda ***stadiorum***, Lk. Skt. Lind. Rush. 24, 13. ***In all these passages the West-Saxon uses*** furlang. [***Goth.*** spaurds (1) ***a course***; (2) ***a distance***: ***O. H. Ger***. spurt ***stadium***.]

It is not clear whether the 'racecourse' sense derives from the 'distance' sense or *vice versa*; the same is true of the Latin word it glosses, ***stadium***, although the [*Online Etymology Dictionary*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stadium) suggests the Greek original of the Latin term suggests that the 'distance' sense was prior.

This is a very shaky foundation upon which to build an origin for *ModE* **sport**—especially since I find no evidence that the OE term survived into ME.

As OP points out, [*Middle English Dictionary*](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED42342) gives ***sport(e*** with the senses:

> 1. (a) Amusement, entertainment; pleasure, fun; also, an activity that brings pleasure or amusement; a pastime or game; also, ?a sexual exploit, an amorous deed [quot. ?c1450, 2nd]; don sportes, to play games; haven (taken) ~, take (one's) pleasure, have fun; ?participate in merrymaking; maken ~, create amusement, make sport; (b) a source of pleasure or delight; (c) joking; foolery; in ~, in jest; connen no ~, to engage in no foolery.
> 2. Solace, consolation; also, ?a means of comfort or consolation; maken ~, to console (sb.), cheer up.

There are also related words, **sportaunce**, **sportelet**, **sporten**, **sportful**, **sporting**.

*MED* sees all of these as "Shortened form[s] of **disport**", "**disporten**, &c., which first appear in ME a generation earlier than **sport(e** and its relatives. For the noun *MED* gives the [following senses](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED12041):

> 1. (a) An activity that offers amusement, pleasure, or relaxation; entertainment, merry-making, fun, recreation; maken ~, to entertain (sb.); taken ~, amuse oneself, have fun; (b) a pastime, sport, or game; also, the game of love, flirtation; (c) in ~, in jest.
> 2. (a) Pleasure taken in an activity or enjoyment derived from it; haven ~, to take pleasure (in sth.), be gratified; (b) consolation, solace; a source of comfort; don ~, to cheer (sb.) up.
> 3. (a) Deportment, conduct; customary behavior, custom, manner; (b) an instance of behavior, an act or activity; don ~, to do something.
> 4. Departure; maken ~, to set out (for a place).

The first two of these senses are clearly identical with those of **sport(e**. They carry over into EME, whence they give rise to the modern senses.

Among the "disportes" mentioned by the *MED* citations are dice, reveling, minstrels singing songs and telling jests, and finding Venus on a bed of gold, as well as recreations which would be regarded as "sports" today, hawking, hunting, angling, archery.

None of the citations alludes to *racing* or reflects (except for one allusion to the "actes and disportes Olimpicalle") a sense of "competitive" sport.

And there is no other *MED* headword of the form *sp?rt**, *sp?rd**, *spr?t**, or *spr?d** which could be taken as derivative of *spyrd*.

It looks like the similarity of the OE term is coincidental, since it cannot be traced into ME.

Comment: What about "sporte" in ME?

Comment: http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=boolean&q1=spoorte&rgn1=Anywhere&operator1=And&q2=&rgn2=Anywhere&operator2=And&q3=&rgn3=Anywhere&size=First+100

Comment: @Anixx  Hah! I was under the impression that MED consolidated spellings under headwords ... let me look farther. ... No. Searches under *sp?rt**, *sp?rd**, *spr?d** and *spr?t** yield nothing derived or derivable from *spyrd* except your own reference. And in that entry the senses are the same as those given for *disport*, or derivative; and the earliest citations are a generation later. I'll modify my response, but stick by my answer.

Comment: Also take into account the Old Norse borrowing "sprint".

Comment: And "spring" which is derived from PIE *sprengh- "rapid movement" (evidently similar to Russian "pryg", jump, "pruzhina", spring).

Comment: @Anixx  See my edited response. That *spyrd* has cognates in other languages tells us nothing about whether it has descendants in English. We can, unambiguously, trace ModE *sport* back to ME *disport* and thence to OF *desporter*, and *desporter* back to Lat *porto*; we cannot trace the ME back to any OE origin.

Comment: How about ‘sport’ as in ‘wearing’? ie ‘he was sporting a snazzy jacket’ or ‘she sported a winning smile’? I wonder where that fits in.